# How to Use Switch Statement To Handle FirebaseAuthException

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, switch-statement

I have a Flutter app that allows users to register/login to their accounts using FirebaseAuth. Signing in requires users to enter their email address and password. I am trying to use a switch statement to handle for when the user is unable to sign in due to entering the wrong email address, wrong password, etc.

login_screen.dart below contains code for the Log In button and when pressed, makes a call to FirebaseAuthHandler (from firebase_auth_handler.dart) when there is a FirebaseAuthException.

login_screen.dart

```
RoundedButton(
            title: 'Log In',
            colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                showSpinner = true;
              });
              try {
                final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: email, password: password);
                if (user != null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, LandingScreen.id);
                }
                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = false;
                });
              } catch (errorCode) {
                FirebaseAuthHandler(errorCode).handleErrorCodes();
                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = false;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
```

firebase_auth_handler.dart

```
    class FirebaseAuthHandler {
  FirebaseAuthHandler(this.errorCode);

  FirebaseAuthException errorCode;

  handleErrorCodes() {
    switch (errorCode) {
      case "[firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.":
        print("Invalid password.");
        break;
      case "[firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.":
        print("Invalid email address.");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error for **switch(errorCode)** that says,

```
Type 'FirebaseAuthException' of the switch expression isn't assignable to the type 'String' of case expressions
```

The two case statements I am using are what's printed to my Console when I print the exceptions. How can I provide a case of type FirebaseAuthException that will work for my switch statement?

Comment: Have you tried `switch (errorCode.code) {` or `switch (errorCode.message) {`?

Comment: @rickimaru I just changed it to switch(errorCode.code) and it got rid of the error, but the print statements aren't firing. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this one out. I changed **switch(errorCode)** to **switch(errorCode.code)** and changed the cases to what I have below. I was able to find a list of error codes for signInWithEmailAndPassword [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) and plugged some of the error codes in for the case expressions.

As @rickimaru commented, you could also use **errorCode.message** instead of **errorCode.code** if you like, as long as you find the corresponding message and plug it in for the case expressions.

```
class FirebaseAuthHandler {

  handleErrorCodes(FirebaseAuthException errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode.code) {
      case "wrong-password":
        print("Invalid password!!!");
        break;
      case "user-not-found":
        print("Invalid email address!!!");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```